# Use one entity symfony class for 2 or many tables in the same database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm developing a web application in which the user can switch the table where he want to record the data. I mean, there might be a table for test mode and another one for prod mode in the same table. For instance I have a tab_article in both mode but the column in them are the same so I want to use just one entity class for them but it will depend on the users choice to say either the data will go in the table for prod or in test.

I also plan to allow the administrator to create other mode so I will generate dynamically all tables for any mode that he creates.

I look for any suggestion.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: Why don't you use different databases test and production, add condition in config file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I thought about that but my problem is on the fact that I have some tables which are common for all the modes like the tab_user for example so if I use different databases,if the administrator insert an user and the mode prod is chosen, the user will not be created in other modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way to solve this problem is handling `loadClassMetadata` Doctrine event.

Simple listener example:

```
class TableEnvRenameListener
{
    private $env;
    public function __construct($env)
    {
        $this->env = $env;
    }

    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();
        $table = $classMetadata->table;
        $table['name'] = str_replace('_env', $this->env, $table['name']);
        $classMetadata->setPrimaryTable($table);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to test if it will solve the issue. Then will this function change the name of the linked table in the entity declaration? or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah. If you need entity's table to be renamed you just have to add `_env` prefix. For example `@Entity(name="_env_table")`. In that case, depending on `env`, it will become `prod_table` or `test_table`...

Comment: Excellent! thank you. I am testing it now. I will give the result after.